# What is the difference between using/not using return in a subprogram?

Tags: c, function, functional-programming, return, return-value

The second piece of code is not giving the correct value as it only passes the value of `r` from what I see. However, I would like to make this code work without using `return` (just for learning how to do it in this other way). Also, what is considered best practice between these two options? Thank you! :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.1416

float area(float r);

int main(void)
{
  float r = 10;
  printf("Area: %.2f", area(r));
  return 0;
}

float area(float r) {
    return PI * r * r;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.1416

float area(float r);

int main(void)
{
  float r = 10;
  printf("Area: %.2f", area(r));
  return 0;
}

float area(float r) {
    PI * r * r;
}
```

Comment: There is no other way. You need to use the `return` statement to return a value. Without it (in your second option) it would be an empty statement that does nothing and the function will either raise a compiler error or return 0 (based on your compiler).

Comment: I'm curious as to where you've heard about this "other way", because either the source is just completely wrong, or you misunderstood something.

Comment: Since you used the FP tag: A function without a return statement converts a function call expression semantically into a statement. You need globale mutable state to use such function in a meaningful way as you need global state for any statement in order to connect it with other statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to make this code work without using return (just for learning how to do it in this other way).

Using `return` is the only way to actually *return* a value from a function.

---

However, the C syntax provides two alternative options:

1. It is possible to pass another pointer as argument to the function, which points to an object in the caller, in which you then assign the value of the expression.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.1416

void area(float r, float *p);

int main(void)
{
  float r = 10;
  float s;
  area(r, &s);
  printf("Area: %.2f", s);
  return 0;
}

void area(float r, float* p) {
   *p = PI * r * r;
   return;
}
```

---

2. It is also possible to define a global object and assign the value of the expression to that global object instead.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.1416

float s;

void area(float r);

int main(void)
{
  float r = 10;
  area(r);
  printf("Area: %.2f", s);
  return 0;
}

void area(float r) {
    s = PI * r * r;
    return;
}
```

But that is considered to be bad practice because the connections from and to the function and with that the actual use of the function are then much harder to understand than using parameters and return types, which on the other hand show the relation and the use of the particular function call pretty good.

The use of global objects shall be avoided if possible although there are cases where a global objects is suitable, if you f.e. use an object in multiple functions and the role of the object is exactly defined. But in the provided example of yours, a global object does not fit very well and shall be avoided.

---

If no value shall be returned, define the return type of the function as of type `void`.

Comment: Are you sure that `return` is mandatory for functions returning `void`? There are multiple examples throughout the standard where the return is omitted, and section 6.8.6.4 only states _"A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function
whose return type is void."_ and _"A function may have any number of return statements."_, which to me means that `return;` is of course legal in such a function, but not strictly required (after all, "any number" presumably includes 0)

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer @RobertS supports Monica Cellio :-) And between the three options we have in this post, which one is considered best practice and why? I guess that based on your answer it is mainly between using pointers or returning the value itself (we discard the use of a global object in this particular case). Thank you!

Comment: @Henry As RobertS already mentioned, using a global variable is considered bad practice, with one notable exception, which is **`errno`**. There are many standard functions which, if something goes wrong, write the cause of the error to errno, so that the user can then check it afterwards. Other than that, you should minimize the usage of global variables (especially if it's just for "returning" a value), because it makes the code harder to read and maintain. The other two options are both regularly used, and which one to choose depends a lot on the specific situation.

Comment: @FelixG "*Are you sure that `return` is mandatory for functions returning `void`?*" - I don´t know exactly. This maybe a worth a question for the `language-lawyer` tag. The definition you provided is indeed pretty loose. I´m seeking in the standard in the meantime, too.

Comment: @Henry The options 1. and 2. are not in competition to each other, thus there is no right and wrong regarding a "best practice". It depends on the situation which option you choose. Also option 3. using global objects isn´t bad in general, it shall only be *avoided* where you could easily use 1. or 2. instead. Means in turn 3. is only beneficial in situations where you have an object which is used in several functions and you don´t want to pass the value of the object either by reference or by value for each and every function again.

Comment: @FelixG every thread has its own errno, so I doubt that it's a global variable..

Comment: @MartinJames good point, in a single-threaded program errno might behave like a global variable, but of course you're right in that it technically isn't.

Comment: The C standard does not require a function with a non-void return type to execute a `return` statement. It just does not define the behavior if the function does not execute a `return` **and** the value of the function is used. (This accommodates functions that perform different operations depending on their parameters, such as a request to set or to get some configuration setting.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I finally deleted that part out of the answer. What about `void` returning functions? Do they need to execute a `return` statement? - Regarding your second sentence - How can a return value be used if a `return` statement wasn´t executed? Or is there anything like a standard-coercion that a function has to return a value by default even if no `return` is executed?

Comment: Hey @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Just applying the pointer logic you explained in another piece of code, but can't seem to get it to work. `void maximum_value(int N, float * VABS, float *maximum)
{
  int i;
  float max;
  max = VABS[0];

  for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
  {
    if (VABS[i] > max)
    {
       max = VABS[i];
    }
  } max=*maximum;
}` In the above subprogram I am trying to pass into the main program its result using a pointer called `*maximum` whose value I am storing in a new variable called `variable_where_maximum_is`. The code: https://screencast.com/t/TdvVPB7p6PTp

Comment: Functions with return type `void` do not need to execute a `return` statement. For a function `f` that has a non-void return type but does returns by flowing to its end without executing a `return`, then `f();` is okay but `x = f();` is not.

Comment: @Henry The last statement is incorrect. Instead of assigning `max` to the object `maximum` is pointing to you assign the value of the object `maximum` is pointing to to `max`.

Comment: That is soo correct @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio!!! Thanks very much for all your help!! Very much appreciated :-))